# Appending Two String Arrays in Tuple

Tags: swift

I am trying to `append` two `Sting` `Arrays` in `tuple` but it gives me error? [image]

This is my class:

```
import UIKit
var tuple : [(String, String)] = []
class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate{

    let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

    var url : [String] = []
    var image : [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad(){

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        for i in tuple{

            url.append(i.0)
            image.append(i.1)
            print("URL values.............. \(url)")
            print("Image values.............. \(image)")
        }


        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(url, forKey: "u")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(image, forKey: "i")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


        var u = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("u")
        var i = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("i")

        tuple.removeAll()
        tuple.append(u,i)

    }
```

When I change the types to this:

```
var u : String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("u") as! String
var i : String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("i") as! String
```

Now it gives me that error:

[image]

How can I append a tuple to an array?

Comment: I would not name an array `tuple`. It's a bit misleading

Comment: You can name tuples: `var images : [(url: String, image: String)] = []`. You can then do `url.append(i.url); image.append(i.image)` instead of `url.append(i.0); image.append(i.1)`

Comment: also, in a for loop, `i` stands for index, while your i contains a tuple. So you should rather do something like `for tuple in images` (naming is important for clean code)

Comment: From the documentation : *Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple*

Comment: What vadian and simpleBob said. The only thing I would add (for completion) is to append a tuple to array, you need to wrap it in a second set of brackets, i.e `array.append((u, i))`. You also shouldn't force downcast. Write some logic to handle the case where the casting fails.

Comment: I tried this `url.append(i.url)` but it gives me error `Value of type 'String' has no member 'url' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code removed]

Also, as a user told you in comment, naming an array `tuple` is bad habit. The name `tuples` would fit already much better

EDIT: As @originaluser2 said, you can also use `tuple.append((u,i))`

EDIT2: I think this is definitely what you're looking for (I also adjusted names to avoid confusion, you should too)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate{

    let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

    var tuples: [(String, String)] = []

    var urls: [String] = []
    var images: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad(){

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        for i in tuples {

            urls.append(i.0)
            images.append(i.1)
            print("URL values.............. \(urls)")
            print("Image values.............. \(images)")
        }


        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(urls, forKey: "u")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(images, forKey: "i")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        // Cast objects as NSArray, since it's a subclass of NSObject
        // Only NSObject derivate classes can be used for these purposes
        let u = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("u") as! NSArray
        let i = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("i") as! NSArray

        tuples.removeAll()

        // For every element of the first NSArray
        for index in 0 ..< u.count {
            // Append in the tuples array the strings at position index
            // of both array
            // NSString and String class are bridged, so you can use them both
            // in order to accomplish your needs. An NSArray btw can store NSString, but not String objects
            tuples.append((u.objectAtIndex(index) as! String,i.objectAtIndex(index) as! String))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives me that error 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxY0lQMnNGUnM3R1E

Comment: Then you're trying to do something wrong: Saving as string an object that is not a string in a String, String tuples array. You should think better at your data model

Comment: I changed tup to `let tup = ("\(u)", "\(i)")` now it works and append in `tuple`.
But it also adds `(\n \` on start and  `\'\n)` on ends. like this `[("(\n    \"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h30Bx4Klxg\"\n)", "(\n    \"1.jpg\"\n)")]`
Are you know or any idea why it adds with this??

Comment: That looks like an array more than a string. Edit: You declare url as [string], that is a string array, not an array. Same for image. If you want do so, you should cast the object as an Array (as! Array) and then fetch the first element. Better approach (if the array shall contain only 1 item) would be saving NSString directly (declaring your vars as NSString instead of String)

Comment: Actually i am just trying to save tuple in NSUserDefaults or locally. But the problem is i have no any idea how i can save it and cant get help from internet also post another question for saving tuple in NSUserDefault but not get any answer. So due to this reason i've trying  to save tuple values in arrays and then  arrays save in NSUserDefaults and then trying to append in again tuple ;(
Can you please check my code for solving it with batter way.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxYTdFYVFwSE9LZzQ

Comment: You can't save tuples in NSUserDefaults.... NSUserDefaults is a class that comes from Objective-C written libraries. Swift supports everything Objective-C can power you (well, almost everything), but it does not apply for the opposite. For this reason, Obj-C is a more flexible language in terms of libraries than Swift. A library that you write in Objective-C can be used in Swift, but viceversa isn't always true. Tuples don't exist in Objective-C, thus they are not part of the AnyObject type. The requirement of being it, is inheriting NSObject base class (that NSArray and NSString do)

Comment: So if you want to store your tuple information, you should split it in two different NSArrays, store them using NSUserDefaults. Load them back when you need them, and then merge them in a tuple (as I show in the code above). For saving them, you have to do something similar. NSUserDefaults can store actually: NSString, NSNumber, NSData, NSDictionary, NSArray, NSData and NSDate only. So split your tuple array into 2 different NSArrays, save them using NSUserDefaults and fetch them back when you need them.